# why does it print both lockcomplete and lockstate when the power button is pressed to lock the phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, springboard

Phone lock

```
darwinNotification name = com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete
darwinNotification name = com.apple.springboard.lockstate
```

Phone unlock

```
darwinNotification name = com.apple.springboard.lockstate
```

When i lock the the phone it prints both. why is that?

Comment: Simple. It posts `lockcomplete` because locking has completed, but it will always post `lockstate` when the state of lock changes. if it existed, you might consider that on unlocking it would post `unlockcomplete`

Comment: how to call a method that is defined in ViewController.m recursively from AppDelegate.m?

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated question. Raise it as an actual question for an naswer